# How to determine if a right click was performed on a Panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, panel

I have a Panel to play media. How can I determine if it was Right clicked? I want to bring up a ContextualMenu on the panel with (Pause, Play, Stop and Start Over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio on your form, add a contextmenustrip, and populate it with the values that you want. The panel has a property called contextmenustrip, all you need to do is set that to the one that you create and visual studio will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 4):

just wire up your ContextMenu to the Panels [`ContextMenu` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenu.aspx)... another option is assign your handler to the [`MouseClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) of the Panel and check the [event args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) for [`Button == MouseButtons.Right`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons.aspx).